# What does NEC require for strapping down conduit and wire here?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec, service

Below is a picture of the current conduit and wire setup for my new underground service into my house with generator automatic transfer switch and manual transfer switch to allow me to switch to an inlet.

[image: Current installation]

The conduit is all very well secured by the ground and the boxes. The piece of SER wire between the meter pan and transfer switch is only secured at the boxes.

What does code require that I do to secure the conduit and/or SER? I'd like to get that squared away before I call for inspection. I am in NJ and we follow the 2014 NEC.

Comment: I have searched quite a bit, but I can't figure out if the ground and/or boxes count as securing things. From my perspective the wire and conduit are secured at the ground and boxes, but I can't tell if NEC agrees.

Comment: My current inspector is very picky about straps within 3' of the box, for the conduit , with a short run and expansion joints they don't make seance to me but the cable would defiantly need a strap in just about every county in Oregon.

Comment: Another interesting question is whether you're allowed to use the conduit as a hanger for the ground wire.  You're not allowed to do that for *anything else*...

Comment: Based on the use of "NEC", I presume you're in the US, however many laws vary state-to-state. Indicating which state (and even city) may well get you a better answer. (Note @EdBeal's comment about "every county in Oregon".)

Comment: @FreeMan I updated to include state; I'm in NJ, and the whole state follows the 2014 edition of NEC. Due to state preemption we do not have local codes in NJ. (Of course some inspectors are picky about different things or interpret the same code differently.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2014 NEC Article 352.30(A) states that PVC conduit should be supported **within** 3' of each outlet box, disconnect, panel, etc. That also Includes strapping the 90% ells you have installed. I can see that you have installed expansion joints so the strap has to go above the joint to allow the joint to expand with the grade.

Also the ground wire is attached above and below the expansion joint binding the joint and connection. You would be better off attaching the ground to the building instead of the conduit as the comments have already indicated.

Good luck.